# GameInput API doesn't work once the SWF is embedded in a HTML page

Tags: actionscript-3

I've built a small demo application to test the [`GameInput`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/GameInput.html) APIs that Adobe released a little while ago. It works perfectly in debug mode, via the .exe and via the .swf that get generated via Flash CC, but when I test the application embedded on a web page, I can no longer use the controller (I am using an Xbox 360 Controller).

I've spent some time researching, and can't find any references to the `GameInput` classes either working or not working when the SWF is embedded on a web page.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get working (perhaps via some extra data in the HTML embed code) or whether this is an obstacle I won't be able to get around?

Comment: Browser's don't expose API's to hardware devices like game controllers, so I'm not sure what a SWF running in a browser is supposed to do in this respect. However, I recall there being some Java project (or perhaps another language) that people were using in conjunction w/Flash to control hardware devices. Take a look at [this page](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/SerialNet#.UwQ-MEJdV4E) for example.

Comment: @SunilD. http://www.gamepadjs.com/

Comment: SWEET! Had no idea that existed. I think the other issue you're facing is the fact that `GameInput` is an AIR class. I'm not going out on a limb this time, and instead will ask: Have you seen any way to run AIR code in the browser? But perhaps you could just use that Javascript API and ExternalInterface?

Comment: @SunilD. Actually, that documentation is outdated. The GameInput APIs have been pushed across into AIR 3.8 and the most recent Flash Player released since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GameInput classes absolutely work in the browser. Support has been there since Flash Player 11.8 (in beta), then officially added with 11.9.

It does come with some caveats:

- Not all devices work; some fringe devices may get ignored by Flash.
- Sometimes the addition of devices that *are* supported don't really work - you may have to disconnect and reconnect them to get them to work.
- Sometimes when using multiple controllers of the same type they get mixed up and only one of them will work.
- Actual reported control ids vary between the Plugin/ActiveX version of Flash (Firefox/Safari/IE/etc) and Pepper (Chrome).
- You usually need to press a button with the proper SWF focused for the GameInputDevice to be detected and reported.

An XBox 360 controller is guaranteed to work. That's FP's main "target", if such a thing exists. I have personally performed dozens of tests with different devices and the (wired) XBox 360 controller is the only one that never gave me any headache.

I have [a published SWF that works for testing which devices have been properly detected](http://hosted.zehfernando.com/key-action-binder/game-input-tester/), and their reported controls, with [source code](https://github.com/zeh/key-action-binder/tree/master/tests/GameInputTester/src) available as well.

As a final note: as is the norm with any HTML-embedded SWF, be sure to always test *in a server*, not using file:///. A local server with XAMPP or whatever will do. Loading SWF content without a server always gives you a lot of restrictions that you have to circumvent and it's generally more effort than it's worth. I wouldn't be surprised if GameInput support was unavailable for SWFs loaded from file:/// on some given browser.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check it out once I get to the office.

Comment: You're right, I went through your list of possible reasons (disconnect, reconnect, press buttons) and now it's working, thanks a lot.